# How replace DTD path Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm opening a XML file with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE relatos PUBLIC "-//SINCODH/DTD relatos 0.97" "relatos.dtd">
<relatos>
</relatos>
```

Now, I want to replace the DOCTYPE tag for a new dtd:

```
<!DOCTYPE relatos SYSTEM "test/dummy/public/midtd.dtd">
```

I'm trying with this, but seems first i need to remove dtd tag existing:

```
docnoko = Nokogiri::XML(doc)
docnoko.create_internal_subset("relatos", nil, "test/dummy/public/midtd.dtd")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, usually Nokogiri makes it really easy to replace nodes or delete them and add something else in, but this requires a bit of a work-around:

```
require 'nokogiri'

old_doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE relatos PUBLIC "-//SINCODH/DTD relatos 0.97" "relatos.dtd">
<relatos>
  <foo />
  <bar />
</relatos>
EOT
```

Create a new document:

```
new_doc = Nokogiri::XML('<relatos/>')
```

Which looks like this:

```
new_doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<relatos/>\n"
```

Then add the new DTD:

```
new_doc.create_internal_subset('relatos', nil, 'test/dummy/public/midtd.dtd')
```

Then append the nodes from the old document to the new one:

```
new_doc.at('relatos').children = old_doc.at('relatos').children
```

Resulting in:

```
new_doc.to_xml # => "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<!DOCTYPE relatos SYSTEM \"test/dummy/public/midtd.dtd\">\n<relatos>\n  <foo/>\n  <bar/>\n</relatos>\n"
```

Here's the code in one chunk:

```
require 'nokogiri'

old_doc = Nokogiri::XML(<<EOT)
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE relatos PUBLIC "-//SINCODH/DTD relatos 0.97" "relatos.dtd">
<relatos>
  <foo />
  <bar />
</relatos>
EOT

new_doc = Nokogiri::XML('<relatos/>')

new_doc.create_internal_subset('relatos', nil, 'test/dummy/public/midtd.dtd')
new_doc.at('relatos').children = old_doc.at('relatos').children
```

You might ask on the Nokogiri-Talk list or their IRC channel as the really smart people hang out there.